# Representing a set of items as a single number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, prime-numbers

I would like to represent a set of "items" as a single number of which I can easily determine some information from it by simple arithmetic:

1. determine if two sets are the same, ignoring ordering of items
2. determine if one set is a super-set of the other

The way I approach this would be to represent each "item" I have as a prime number. The set is simply the product of all items. #1 can be found by easily by comparing if the set number is the same. #2 I can determine if the smaller number goes perfectly (without remainder) into the larger number.

Would my above idea work? I believe there must be some formal research in this area already but I've not found much material online. The closest I've found are:

- https://medium.com/mop-developers/convert-a-combination-to-a-single-number-eb4c9ea5476a
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system

But they don't contain any in-depth analysis like how many elements can be represented by how large a number, etc.

Off the top of my head:

If my "set number" is 4096 bits. That's around `10e+1000`. It can only fit 10 prime number elements in the `10e+100` range. It seems with this method the number of elements I can fit in is very limited. (I would like to choose a "random" prime number for each item in my set with a small enough collision so I can choose them without any pre-conditions)

Comment: For $n$ large, the product of all the primes up to $n$ is roughly $e^n$. Now $10^{1000}$ is roughly $e^{2300}$, so you could use all the primes up to $2297$. There are $342$ such primes, and no danger of collision.

Comment: Hmm.. I was hoping it was larger than that. My set may have millions of records. Looks like this method is not viable as it will make the numbers unwieldly large fast

Comment: If you have a million records, then you have $2^{1000000}$ possible subsets, which is $10^{300000}$, roughly. That's way way way bigger than the $10^{1000}$ numbers of $4096$ bits. No matter what you choose to do, you're going to have to live with some likelihood of collisions. But isn't "hashing" the appropriate search term here?

Comment: I didn't find anything related to hashing that has the property where I can quickly determine if one set is a super set of the other. If you know any hashing algorithms that can solve that, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: There is no general sublinear algorithm to determine whether two sets are equal or a set is a subset of the other set.

Comment: Yes, it occurred to me that hashing isn't designed to respect partial orders.